# Multithreading in Rails - How to Merge threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to multithread a process in Rails. I have a large dataset called `modelA` and I currently have a process that divides this into the days it was created (many rows per day) and then runs a process on each day. Finally the results of each day are added into an array in the order which they occurred. How do I multithread and return this?

```
  def function()
    ...
    if originalDate > Time.now - 60 * 60 * 24
      movingDate = Time.now - 60 * 60 * 24 * 31
    else
      movingDate = originalDate
    end
    begin
      dayFeed = newFeed.select{|obj| obj.created_at < movingDate + 60 * 60 * 24}
      dayFeed = dayFeed.select{|obj| obj.created_at > movingDate}
      … A lot of calculations to determine summary…
      b << summary
      totals = summary
      movingDate += 60 * 60 * 24
    end while movingDate <= Date.today
    [b, totals]
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Just create multithreads and use them like a func, gather add all results in an array in the main thread.

I've copy and past a part of code from this tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm
this should solve your problem:

```
count = 0
arr = []

10.times do |i|
   arr[i] = Thread.new {
      sleep(rand(0)/10.0)
      Thread.current["mycount"] = count
      count += 1
   }
end

arr.each {|t| t.join; print t["mycount"], ", " }
puts "count = #{count}"
```